Most Efficient way to compute array
I ran into a problem while solving this question and I am not sure about the approach of how to find the most efficient approach and time complexity for finding this optimal subsequence for this question.
"Suppose you are given an array $ [ 1 … n ]$ of n positive real numbers. A subsequence of this array is considered feasible if it does not include any three consecutive elements from the original array. An optimal subsequence is defined as a feasible subsequence that maximizes the sum of its elements. For example, if $A=[6,4,15,4,10,5,7,3,9,10,2,5,8]$ an optimal subsequence would be $[6,15,10,7,9,10,5,8]$, resulting in a total sum of $70$.
Our goal is to compute an optimum subarray (a feasible subarray with maximum possible elements sum), given the following option: DP - $O(n^2)$, Greedy - $O(n \log n)$, NP-Hard problem unless $P=NP$, DP - $O(n)$, Divide and Conquer - $O(n \log n)$" - by Professor Shahin Kamali for the class Design and Analysis of Algorithms
What I have tried:
I have considered various algorithmic techniques, such as dynamic programming, greedy methods, and divide-and-conquer, but I’m not sure which is best suited for this problem or how to implement it efficiently:
Dynamic Programming: At first I believe dynamic programming might be the best approach here, as it can efficiently track optimal solutions by systematically considering each element's choices while avoiding three consecutive element. My idea is to keep track of possible sums up to each element in $O(n)$ time.
Divide & Conquer: This could be well-suited for this problem because it allows us to recursively split the array into two halves, solving for the maximum feasible subarray sum in each half while respecting the constraint of no three consecutive elements. By dividing the array, we can handle each part independently, then combine results from the left and right halves with a careful merging step that ensures the constraint is maintained across the midpoint. This approach results in a time complexity of $O(n \log n)$, leveraging the efficient recursive structure of divide-and-conquer to handle subarray constraints effectively.
I am not very sure with DP because DP problems usually require more than $O(n)$, plus this problem doesn't look like it is NP-hard so I didn't try it yet. I hope there could be any insight of which approach is better for this question.

Better, well suited, most efficient depend on measure - try least energy spent solving a big problem instance or least development effort.

What exactly does "any three consecutive elements" mean? That is, I understand that the sequence [6,4,15,...] could not be feasible because those three elements are consecutive in the original array. But could [6,3,9...] be included? 6 and 3 aren't adjacent in the original array, but 3 and 9 are.

There is an easy $\mathcal{O}(n)$ solution in dynamic programming.
Consider the following functions:

$f_0(i)$ is the maximum sum without three consecutives values, up to index $i$, without the value $i$ selected;
$f_1(i)$ is the maximum sum without three consecutives values, up to index $i$, with the value $i$ selected, but without the value $i - 1$ selected;
$f_2(i)$ is the maximum sum without three consecutives values, up to index $i$, with the values $i$ and $i-1$ selected.

Meaning $f_j(i)$ has $j$ consecutives values at the end of the corresponding subsequence.
There are easy relations to compute $f_0(i + 1)$, $f_1(i + 1)$, $f_2(i + 1)$ knowing $f_0(i)$, $f_1(i)$ and $f_2(i)$. For example:
$$f_2(i + 1) = f_1(i) + A[i + 1]$$
What you want is $\max(f_0(n), f_1(n), f_2(n))$. Having an algorithm computing the maximum sum, it is not that hard to modify it to return the corresponding subsequence.
